Undefined error while loading Survey-creator-core using RequireJS
I am using requireJS in my project and want to load survey-core and survey-creator-core.
survey-creator-core has a dependency on survey-core when i checked the js file of survey-creator-core.
I got the survey-core module when i import it in my ts file but survey-creator-core stays undefined.
here is the code
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var require = {
            baseUrl: "/bundles",
            paths: {
                jquery: "/bundles/jquery",
                moment: "/bundles/moment",
                bootstrap: "/bundles/bootstrap",
                select2: "/bundles/select2",
                "knockout" : "/bundles/knockout",
                "survey-core": "/bundles/survey-core",
                "survey-creator-core": "/bundles/survey-creator-core",
                "survey-knockout-ui": "/bundles/survey-knockout-ui",
                "survey-creator-knockout": "/bundles/survey-creator-knockout"
            },
            shim: {
                moment: {
                    deps: ["jquery"]
                },
                bootstrap: {
                    deps: ["jquery", "moment"]
                },
                select2: {
                    deps: ["jquery"]
                },
                "survey-creator-core": {
                    deps: ["survey-core"]
                },
                "survey-creator-knockout": {
                    deps: ["survey-creator-core"]
                }
            },
            deps: ["jquery", "moment", "bootstrap"],
            urlArgs: "v=@version"
        };
    </script>

    <script src="~/lib/requirejs/require.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

this is how i use it in one of my cshtml file
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["jquery", "bootstrap", "select2"], function () {
            require(["survey-core", "survey-creator-core"], function (Survey, SurveyCreator) {
                require(["./test"], function (ea) {
                    var c = new ea.test();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}

In the above code SurveyCreator is coming as undefined.
Survey is loaded successfully.

Can you share a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

It is hard to reproduce your example and pinpoint what is the main issue in resolving the dependency graph.
I have created a working sample based of your code, but I had to do it under assumptions that may differ from your setup.
Main difference is that I have used all the "latest" versions of the JavaScript dependencies, which might differ from yours. This is based of package.json I have added to quickly get things up and running.
Anyways, the code sample I have added in GitHub, so you can run it and triage on your end.
Code Sample
https://github.com/endatix/samples-surveyjs/tree/main/RequireJs.InlineConfiguration
Note couple of major changes in the sample:

I have refactored the javascript inlined via the Scripts section to only use single required call in the module initialization e.g. require(["select2", "survey-core", "survey-creator-knockout", "../js/test", "jsonData"], function (select2, Survey, SurveyCreatorKnockout, testJs, jsonData) {.... This is done as it improves readability and it also makes resolving the dependencies linear, which simplifies the resolution path.

For survey-creator-knockout I have added all of the module dependencies, even though it's not required since the library defines them in its module definition. Still, I have added them as it's more explicit and transparent.


survey-creator-knockout": {
                    deps: [
                        "survey-core",
                        "survey-creator-core",
                        "survey-knockout-ui",
                        "knockout",
                    ],
                },

Main Files from the sample
_Layout.cshtml
...
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var require = {
            baseUrl: "/bundles",
            paths: {
                jquery: "jquery",
                moment: "moment",
                bootstrap: "bootstrap.bundle",
                select2: "select2",
                knockout: "knockout-latest",
                "survey-core": "survey.core",
                "survey-creator-core": "survey-creator-core",
                "survey-knockout-ui": "survey-knockout-ui",
                "survey-creator-knockout": "survey-creator-knockout",
                "jsonData": "../js/json-data"
            },
            shim: {
                moment: {
                    deps: ["jquery"],
                },
                bootstrap: {
                    deps: ["jquery"],
                },
                select2: {
                    deps: ["jquery"],
                },
                "survey-creator-core": {
                    deps: ["survey-core"],
                },
                "survey-knockout-ui": {
                    deps: ["survey-core", "knockout"],
                },
                "survey-creator-knockout": {
                    deps: [
                        "survey-core",
                        "survey-creator-core",
                        "survey-knockout-ui",
                        "knockout",
                    ],
                },
            },
            deps: ["jquery", "bootstrap", "moment"],
            urlArgs: "v=@version"
        };
    </script>
    <script src="~/lib/requirejs/require.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
...

Home\Index.cshtml
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div id="surveyCreatorContainer" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["select2", "survey-core", "survey-creator-knockout", "../js/test", "jsonData"], function (select2, Survey, SurveyCreatorKnockout, testJs, jsonData) {
            console.log("Survey:", Survey);
            console.log("SurveyCreatorKnockout:", SurveyCreatorKnockout);

            if (SurveyCreatorKnockout && jsonData) {
                $(function () {
                    const options = {
                        showLogicTab: true,
                    };
                    const creator = new SurveyCreatorKnockout.SurveyCreator(options);
                    creator.JSON = jsonData.surveyJSON;
                    creator.render("surveyCreatorContainer");
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
}

Not sure if you have checked this already, but here's the official sample for SurveyJS with RequireJS, which I find veery helpful too - https://github.com/surveyjs/requirejs-example/blob/master/index.html
Hope this helps!

You can find a sample demo which shows how to integrate the latest SurveyJS component version with RequireJS at https://github.com/surveyjs/requirejs-example/issues/1#issue-2496990419.
